# exported indesign file to pdf, then back to indesign, lost original files

Tags: pdf, import

I was directed here from Graphic Design Stack Exchange.

The original indesign files were lost, all we have is the File>Save As>*.PDF file remaining. We would like to convert pdf back to indesign. The end result is to rebuild the database in excel, if there are any suggestions to convert directly to excel that would save several steps. If you need to see a sample, let me know. The text is stacked (vertically) and I want to breakout from this format: (stacked vertically) 
Name, 
Street Address, 
City, State, ZIP, 
Area Phone, 
website

into this: Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Area, Phone, website (horizontally)
This is NOT a table copy and paste.
Any suggestions are deeply appreciated along with software suggestions to accomplish this. Many thanks in advance for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is delimiting the text blocks, try capturing the text with copy all, paste into a new Indesign document, and use the Find/Change function to turn the delimiters (hopefully soft returns) into tabs. Best approach the Find/Change function with caution, i.e.: find, change and find next; not change all!
I believe you could then take that text raw into excel, but that's beyond my realm.
Also watch for Adobe's sketchy order of appearance, equally mysterious!